# Background notifications for iOS Apps?

Tags: iphone

Under iOS, I am aware that there are some circumstances where an app that is anticipated to be in the background can still receive notifications from the OS (e.g. CoreLocation updates or registered geo-fences or VOIP calls). Are background notifications available for other events, e.g. when a photo is taken/added or when network status changes (specifically allowing one to recognize and react when a known/particular WiFi network is joined)?

Comment: You need to be more specific.  Stating the problem that you're trying to solve and the steps you've taken so far to try and solve it would go a long way.

Comment: I really cannot be more specific without telling more than I ought to about my client's project.

Answer (score 1):

No, the background calls that can happen are pretty clearly enumerated, and photos / network status changes are not included in the list.

You can be woken up for other reasons and check things like network availability and photo library entries (although you cannot know what network you have joined).

Comment: Do you know of any resource that calls them all out?

Comment: Just search for iOS background tasks, there are a ton of resources and articles on the subject.